# Remove entire line from csv if matches a string from within a txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a csv formatted like:

```
Username,Email,Fn,Ln,BusUnit,Department,Manager
USER1@domain.COM,USER1@domain.com,USER1,Ops,Whse,"""MGR1"""
USER2@domain.COM,USER2@domain.com,USER2,Proc,Acct,"""MGR2""
```

I have a txt file formatted like:

```
USER1@domain.COM
USER2@domain.COM
```

I would like to remove all lines in the CSV unless they match on any of the emails in the txt file.

This is clearly incorrect, but it's what I have so far

```
$users = import-csv .\user.csv
$unresolved = gc .\unresolved.txt

get-content $users |? {$_ -match $unsresolved} |export-csv export.csv -notype
```

Answer (score 1):

What's `$lms`? Why is `get-content` there on the last line? How about...

```
$users = import-csv .\user.csv
$unresolved = gc .\unresolved.txt

$users |? {$_.Email -notin $unresolved} |export-csv export.csv -notype
```

Comment: Sorry, the $lms thing was a typo i forgot to change when i posted it, thanks for the reply!